# Decode JSON using Swift 4 with Youtube Analytics for nested unkeyed array

Tags: json, swift, youtube-api, decode, youtube-data-api

So I'm facing a bit of an issue when using the Youtube Analytics API, which returns JSON like below:

```
{
 "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
 "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "views",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   6
  ]
 ]
}
```

I need to access the value 6?

The structs I have created to access this value do not seem to be working, I presume it is to do with accessing an unkeyed array.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let rows: [Row]?
}

struct Row: Decodable {
    let value: String?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        value = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self)
    }
}
```

Then to access the value:

```
let jsonReturn = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
let row = jsonResult.rows![0]
let value = row.value
```

However I'm not sure that even the accessing to the value is correct either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"rows": [
    [
        6
    ]
]
```

You have an array inside an array here, so write

```
let rows: [[Int]]
```

instead of

```
let rows: [Row]
```

, since a class requires a dictionary since a class has names it uses to refer to values. It would have been correct with:

```
"rows": [
    {
        "value": "6"
    {
]
```

`"6"` since you tried to decode it to a `String?`, not an `Int` which the api gave you with `6`.

You can access the data in rows as usual:

```
response.rows[0][0]
```

For more ways to access an array you can work through
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Tip: You can use app.quicktype.io to get the structure for a given json immediately.

Comment: Thanks you for quick reply. I am still unsure how to access the value. If I use the suggestion `response[0][0]`, i.e. `let value = response[0][0]` I am returned with 'Response' has no subscript members. @Fabian

Comment: @JamesFaulkner Missed that rows is the array! Try `response.rows[0][0]`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much @Fabian

Answer (score 0):

you need to have identical Struct, in order to decode the response into the Object, and as its JSON its [Key:Value] each Key is a String that indicates whats the Value is, so the Value can be an array or an array of arrays or another object even the value can be anything in your case

```
{
 "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
 "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "views",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   6
  ]
 ]
}
```

first index, (kinds : youtubeAnalytics#resultTable) so its String: String value 
next index is (columnHeader:  ) so its String:  this object is key: value too, that have keys name, columnType, DataType 
so the final value of how to decode this particular response is simple as below code, and it will give you an  idea how to think about the JSON's and decoding in the future hopefully

```
    struct ColumnHeader: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var columnType: String?
    var dataType: String?
}
struct response: Codable {
    var kind: String?
    var columnHeaders: [ColumnHeader?]
    var rows: [[Int]?]
}
// after we have the data and decode it you can access the object easily as the following,
let obj = ColumnHeader(name: "test", columnType: "test", dataType: "test")
let resp = response(kind: "test2", columnHeaders: [obj], rows: [[2,4],[4,5]])

resp.kind
resp.columnHeaders[0]?.name
```